# How to import Vuex Store into external JS file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

Im trying to import the Vuex Store to my JS Api client but i keep getting this error;

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15__.default.commit is not a function

I import it like this;

```
import Store from '../store/login'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
```

And i want to mutate my JWT token and use commit like this

```
Store.commit('jwtRefresh', { jwt })
```

My console also logs this exact line of code as the error. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you also add your `store/login` file?

Comment: Your way works for me when I imported main store object. Try importing main store instead of module.